# plot linear discriminant analysis in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I would like to plot two matrices in scatter plot diagram. How can I do that? I like that this plot looks like [image: ([this][1])]

I'm calculating linear disciminant analysis on two classes with Fischer's method. This is what I calculate:

```
XM1 <- matrix(data=c(4,2, 2,4, 2,3, 3,6, 4,4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
XM2 <- matrix(data=c(9,10, 6,8, 9,5, 8,7, 10,8), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
mi1 <- apply(XM1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = "mean")
mi2 <- apply(XM2, MARGIN = 2, FUN = "mean")
Sb <- (mi1-mi2)%*%t(mi1-mi2)
sum.cov <- (cov(XM1)+cov(XM2)) 
SwSb <- solve(sum.cov)%*%Sb
eg <- eigen(SwSb)
```

How do I plot these two matrices (one with circles, second with squares) with `abline` (using `eigenval` result)?

Comment: Your example does not run. What is `sum.cov`?

Comment: where is the sum.cov matrix?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to paste: it's: sum.cov <- (cov(X1)+cov(X2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [`ggplot2`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/) solution. First you have to bring your data in a appropriate form:

```
mdf <- as.data.frame( rbind(XM1, XM2) )
names(mdf) <- c("x1", "x2")
mdf$f <- c( rep( "a", nrow(XM1) ), rep( "b", nrow(XM2) ) )
head(mdf)
  x1 x2 f
1  4  2 a
2  2  4 a
3  2  3 a
4  3  6 a
5  4  4 a
6  9 10 b
```

And than this produces a plot similar to the one you showed:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( mdf, aes(x=x1, y=x2, col=f) ) +
  geom_point( size = 4, aes(shape = f) ) +
  geom_abline( slope = eg$vectors[2,1] / eg$vectors[1,1], colour = "green"  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,15)) +
  expand_limits( y = 0, x = 0) +
  labs( title = paste("LDA projection vector with highest eigen value =", round(eg$values[1], 2)) ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, but I need your help, because I did calculate "result - eg in quicker way, just with function `(solve(sum.cov))%*%(mi1-mi2)`. I can't find a way to repair or modify your code to use this data (drawing abline with that result). the result is: `           [,1]
[1,] -1.7076412
[2,] -0.7840532`. Thanks again.

Comment: I did repair the `slope = eg$vectors[2,1] / eg$vectors[1,1]` with `slope = eg[2,1] / eg[1,1]`, so I hope this works fine, because test this and repair on different data. (in variable `eg` is saved the result from function I wrote above: `eg <- (solve(sum.cov))%*%(mi1-mi2)`.